# C++ program to make the invisible and not displayed on your desktop

Tags: c++

I can do to speak English poorly, I hope to understand what I want.
I am still trying to make an invisible program, but nothing came of the program to make invisible.
I need a program that makes the program invisible to the desktop.
The program should include in its processes and make it if you pay with a name.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean like a service?

Comment: or a daemon or a command line program - you need to give more information and also which OS

Comment: what platform are you using? windows? or OSX or linux?

Comment: Perhaps you wish to hide the console window:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/622592/win32-programming-hiding-console-window

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, I think you need to take a look in to writing [Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y817hyb6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Then services are one way to go.  No (by default) desktop interaction, start up on system start-up.  There are some caveats as you will learn about considering what user account they run under, but yes, they are "invisible" (though still exposed through a task manager or process explorer).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the operating system.  In UNIX/Linux, files whose name begins with a "." are default not listed or rendered.