# Sending key "hangs" PC in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sendkeys, freeze

My PC hangs when I `send key` in `Form_Shown()` and placing `Breakpoint` at `Form_KeyDown()`

```
 private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {           //breakpoint here
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("caught");
        }
 }
 private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        SendKeys.Send("A");
 }
```

Comment: I am sending key when form is shown. So it must be at form only

Comment: @Jani: Same result. HANG........

Comment: Dude do you run Windows Vista?

Comment: Read some suggestion and cautions on this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I repro, Win7 and VS2008.  That looks like a fairly nasty deadlock, you can get out of it by pressing Ctrl+Esc on the keyboard.  By default, SendKeys uses a windows hook to inject the keys.  Windows hooks can have fairly unpleasant side effects but I wouldn't hesitate to call this a Windows bug.

To fix it, use Project + Add New Item and select the Application Configuration File item template.  Make it look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="SendKeys" value="SendInput"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

If this is really meant to send a keystroke to your form then there are better ways to accomplish that.

Comment: +1 for attempting (and succeeding) to repro.  I expected to see answers along the line of "You can't lock up the PC with .NET apps".  I have, though typically through GDI+ (blue screen), but anyways, good answer.

Comment: i couldnt bring the taskmanager, left the machine to restart! didnt expect the control + Esc to do th trick! +1!!