# Best method to access the Console object in a Windows Forms application?

Tags: .net, winforms, kernel32

I am attempting to make my GUI app have a CLI frontend (not the opposite).

I have been able to process arguments without an issue (thanks to `System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`), but I am curious what *the best* way to gain access to write output to the console.

I have found reference to [`AllocConsole()`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.allocconsole), but it is unclear if this is the only method, as I'd much prefer something revealed in managed code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's also AttachConsole but that's always a mistake since it allows output to get intermingled.

AllocConsole() is it.  Just creating a form that acts like a console would be the more Winformy way.  With the considerable advantage that the user closing it doesn't cause your program to abort.

Comment: I actually don't wish for a console interface to _co-exist_ with the forms interface; therefore your method isn't important for my current usage, but may be for other usage requirements.  If I use AllocConsole(), [as expected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681944(VS.85).aspx) a new console was spawned.  It appears that [AttachConsole()](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/AttachConsole,.html) will allow me to attach to the console that is the cmd.exe host process!  Thanks!

Comment: for future reference: I was stuck with another problem and this hacky solution worked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305257/using-attachconsole-user-must-hit-enter-to-get-regular-command-line/2463039#2463039 ewww.