# Is there a way to combine Console and GUI applications in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, console-application

HOMEWORK: 
Over the course of the semester, I have created about a dozen applications in C#. While most of them are console applications, three of them are GUI apps. As a final project, our instructor has asked us to create a portfolio program which displays a menu from which the user can select which console application to run.

Being the overachiever that I am, I would like to create a single program that would allow the user to select ANY program created during the semester, console OR GUI.

While I've found a lot of q&a's that address allowing a program to run EITHER as a GUI or Console, I'm not sure those are quite applicable to my situation. [This link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/3273ff67-2f97-4df5-b5df-2216690a5d8c/console-and-gui-app-in-one?forum=winforms) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682633/both-cli-and-gui-application) seem to most CLOSELY match what I'm trying to do. Part of the problem is that we're just starting to scratch the surface of GUI programming this semester, so I don't know a lot of what I don't know. This makes it difficult to ask the right questions and determine how relevant a link is.

My approach is to create a GUI menu. Some of the menu items would launch a Console app inside a Console window, and some of the menu items would launch their respective GUI apps. Does anyone have any practical advice or relevant links that would help guide me to a solution?

Comment: overachiever? - Put all your code in DLLs and load them all dynamically using MEF and then show a WPF Tile-based UI that allows you to choose from the apps. Now that `is` an overachievement.

Comment: you can also create a console control for WPF that reads and uses Console.out and Console.in and then just run the console application without a console.

Comment: Whether the UI is a console application or a GUI is just an interface concern. You should structure all of your core logic in a Class library project and then you can create different interfaces for it (in separate projects).

Comment: compile all project, shove all the exe in the new project ouput and loop in the Directory and list all the exe. then simple Process.Start("app.exe"); ?