# log4net BasicConfigurator is not printing on console

Tags: c#, linux, log4net, monodevelop

I decided to use log4net to handle all the logging activities for the application I am working on... after reading through documentation, I decided to start making experiments, but failed miserably at the very first attempt

The application is being developed with c# using MonoDevelop 3.0.3.2 in a fairly standard Debian 7 distribution, in order to later be deployed on Linux machines.

The code is trivial so far and follows the very early steps in the log4net documentation, and is quoted at the end of the post.

The problem is that the logger does not print anything to console; while trying to understand what's going wrong, I looked intoo it with the debugger; I see that the **log** reference contains the AppendersCollection, which unfortunately is empty I guess that something is not working properly  during configuration and I have no appenders, hence there is no log output.

What am I missing? any suggestion? Is there some sort of a known issue for the combination of MonoDevelop-Linux-log4net I am not aware of?

```
using System;
using log4net;
using log4net.Config;

namespace TestLog4Net
{
    class MainClass
    {
        private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MainClass));

        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            BasicConfigurator.Configure();

            Console.WriteLine ("Hello World!");
            log.Info("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I did some tests loading the configuration file. 
I created 3 loggers each with its own appender, two are rolling file appenders, and one is the console appender.
Then I log "Hello World!" on each logger. 
The rolling file loggers work as expected, while the output from the ConsoleLogger is nowhere to be found. I checked with the Debugger and the  *clogger* object does NOT display an empty AppenderCollection, but there no output anyway. Below you can find the updated code along with the configuration file.

```
using System;
using log4net;
using log4net.Config;

namespace TestLog4Net
{
    class MainClass
    {

        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            XmlConfigurator.Configure(new System.IO.FileInfo("app.config"));

            ILog rflogger1 = LogManager.GetLogger("RFLoggerOne");
            ILog rflogger2 = LogManager.GetLogger("RFLoggerTwo");
            ILog clogger = LogManager.GetLogger("CLogger");

            rflogger1.Info("Hello World!");
            rflogger2.Info("Hello World!");
            clogger.Info("Hello World!");

            Console.WriteLine ("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<log4net>
<appender name="CAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AnsiColorTerminalAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="RFAppender1" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="rf1.log"/>
    <appendToFile value="true"/>
    <rollingStyle value="Composite"/>
    <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd"/>
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10"/>
    <maximumFileSize value="1000000"/>
    <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline"/>
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="RFAppender2" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="rf2.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />

    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%level %thread %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>


<logger name="CLogger">
    <level value="ALL"/>
    <appender-ref ref="CAppender"/>
</logger>

<logger name="RFLoggerOne">
    <level value="ALL"/>
    <appender-ref ref="RFAppender1"/>
</logger>

<logger name="RFLoggerTwo">
    <level value="ALL"/>
    <appender-ref ref="RFAppender2"/>
</logger>


<root>
    <level value="ALL"/>
</root>
</log4net>
```

Comment: Can you show your log4net configuration in your app.config or/and log4net config?

Comment: @peer: the code attached is supposed to be using the BasicConfigurator, and according to documentation, the config file is not needed... In the meanwhile I have made some tests with a configuration file, and found out that I am having problems with the ConsoleAppender, while the RollingFileAppender is working fine, let me update the original post with new code and config file.

Answer (score 0):

Which kind of project do you use? A Console Application?
There are several cases you wont see any output on std::out or std::err on your console.
Have a look at this post:
[Can one executable be both a console and GUI application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493536/can-one-executable-be-both-a-console-and-gui-application/494000#494000)

Comment: When the project has been created it was created as C# Console Application in MonoDevelop, and the source attached is the only source file being part of the project. I have not tweaked anything in the project settings since the project was created, and the prject was created for the sole purpose of doing a few tests with log4net. So I would dare to say that it is a Console Application.